# Proving $S\subseteq\Bbb R^n$ is closed iff $\partial S\subseteq S$- verification

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

This question has been posted multiple times on the site, for example, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222481/proof-about-boundary-points-and-closed-sets/222499#222499), but I've noticed others used different definitions of $A\subseteq\Bbb R^n$ being closed and of its boundary. I would just like to ask for verification based on the equivalent definitions we started from.

> **definition 1.** A subset $S\subseteq\Bbb R^n$ is said to be closed if $\Bbb R^n\setminus S$ is open.
>
> **definition 2.**  Boundary $\partial S$ of the set $S\subseteq\Bbb R^n$ is defined as $\partial S=\overline S\cap\overline{\Bbb R^n\setminus S}.$
>
> **proposition**: $S\subseteq\Bbb R^n$ is closed $\iff$ $S=\overline S.$

---

**My work:**

$\boxed{\Rightarrow}: $ Suppose $S\subseteq\Bbb R^n$ is closed. Then $S=\overline S\quad\&\quad\partial S=\overline S\cap\overline{\Bbb R^n\setminus S}\subseteq \overline S\implies \partial S\subseteq S.$

$\boxed{\Leftarrow}:$ Suppose $\partial S\subseteq S.$ Then, $$\Bbb R^n\setminus S\subseteq\Bbb R^n\setminus\partial S=(\Bbb R^n\setminus\overline S)\cup(\Bbb R^n\setminus\overline{\Bbb R^n\setminus S})\tag 1$$
On the other hand, $$\Bbb R^n\setminus S\subseteq\overline{\Bbb R^n\setminus S}\implies\Bbb R^n\setminus\overline{\Bbb R^n\setminus S}\subseteq S\tag 2$$
so, $(1)$ and $(2)$ give $$\Bbb R^n\setminus S\subseteq\Bbb R^n\setminus\overline S\implies \overline S\subseteq S\tag 3$$
$(3)$ and inclusion $S\subseteq\overline S$ give $S=\overline S,$ so $S$ is closed.

---

Is there any mistake in my reasoning? For the clarity, should I include anything else (possibly proven in lectures)?

Comment: Does your notation $\overline{S}$ mean $\overline{S}:=S\cup L$ where $L$ are the limit points of sequences in $S$?

Comment: @Snoop, yes, $\overline S=S\cup S'$ is the closure of $S$.